Thumbnail or Preview for Word/PDF document in SharePoint Document Library
I am using SharePoint 2016 on premise and we do not have Office Online sever installed. I have a requirement to generate preview of Documents/PDF files stored in SharePoint document library. I am able to achieve this for PDF somehow by loading them in Iframe but for word documents it is not working. I prefer Jquery or any external plugins available to do so. Any suggestions will be helpful!
Thank you!
I tried using client side rendering but it is not working.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Dear team, i am looking for code to preview word files in sharepoint document library or any paid libraries available to do so.
